# Cannot create Elementor Posts page in Wordpress although I have selected in Reading page

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to use my Posts page with Elementor modules.

I have done my Homepage like that

but cannot do the same with Posts page.

I have created an empty page,

added some modules.

And selected this page as Posts page in Reading page.

But when I click a page on my website,

my Elementor Posts page is not seen,

the default Wordpress page is seen.

Update :

I'm using Neve theme on Wordpress v5.8

My website address is [Tubefavorites.com](https://www.tubefavorites.com/tr)

My homepage with Elementor and posts page with default Wordpress has different fonts

and my homepage and posts page's components are in different order.

(In homepage its Tags, Categories, ...

In my posts page its Tags, Last Posts, ...

I'm working online in browser (its not local).

There is no error on Chrome Console.

Update end.

Currently I'm trying this in Turkish pages.

I will make the English Elementor page after I fix this.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried, edit with elemntor buttons?

Comment: I think your question is a bit confusing.. You meaning sidebar by saying side page? Do you have any theme installed that overwrites the default setup of side page you said and that is the reason you are not see it?

Comment: @Earid I have tried but currently that button become not seen after I have selected my content page as side page in settings.

Comment: @Kiriakos Grhgoriadhs thanks for asking, I don't know the English name of it, I use Turkish. But I don't meen sidebar. Its my content page. I have said side page to it, sorry

Comment: I have corrected the question with the correct names.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Elementor enabled for post?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thus, if I understood correctly, you have created a page post and want to add it as homepage. You should go to settings - reading and select via dropdown the page you have created! Then, you will see your page as homepage and not the default one

There is also an explanation in support forum, that someone has the same problem. Please read below:
"*Looks like you’re trying to edit your Posts page that has been assigned in your WordPress Reading settings (Settings > Reading). If this is the case, you may not be able to edit the assigned Posts page directly with Elementor (Basic version).
You can try deselecting the page (in the “Posts Page” box within your Reading settings) then try editing this page with Elementor*"

link to the source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-load-posts-page-with-elementor/

Thus, disable your page through Settings - Reading, edit/modify (whatever you want) your Post page. After that, you could add your page blog posts URL to the meny item (or use this URL to wherever is nessecary)

**EDITED**
What plugin are you using for the translations?
I saw your homepage playing correct, right? Thus, you have selected your custom page correctly, through the Settings - Reading.
Now, if you want to see the same results in Turkish, you need to translate your home page too! So, add the translation in turkish language too, or duplicate the english version for turkish one and it will play!

**UPDATED**
I think there is an issue with the blog page (and single post template, as I am reading in WP forum for this theme). Try to check inside Appearence -> Customize, if there is any options there, thus could change the blog template. Somehow the theme overwrites your options. Furthermore, take a look at the blog theme's doc here:
https://docs.themeisle.com/article/1306-neve-blog-archive-options

Comment: Yes I used the Reading page. 
I have selected my main page from there, and want to select mu content as content page. Is its name is homepage? I have selected it but its not working as I say. The default Wordpress page is working rather than Elementor page. But main page is working.

Comment: You should select the page you create in settings - reading. The name of page could be anything not homepage.. for example if you named the page you already create "My home" this one should select from wordpress (settings - reading)

Comment: I have selected it as Posts page in Reading page, as I say...

Comment: Did you make it to work it out?  
inside Settings - Reading, there are two options (list boxes)> The first one is for your home page, the second one is for the Blog Posts page. If you want to have your page as home page of your website, you should select this page in the first listbox.. I guess you did that, right?

Comment: Yes I chose their pages for both.

Comment: ok.. give us more info please! what theme are you using? is your website online, or using somthing like xampp to work on? Moreover, open the console log and give a feedback if there is any jquery or any errors in general

Comment: Kiriakos Grhgoriadhs Thank you, I have added all these infos to my question. You are right, I had to describe these.

Comment: Reply for EDITED: I use Polylang for multilang. My default lang is Turkish. I haven’t done Element modules with English page yet.

Comment: Perhaps, that is the reason you have wordpress default page; You should translate the page and set as default

Comment: But the page that does not work with Elementor (posts page) is also in Turkish, too. (both homepage and posts page is in default language, Turkish)

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that, I have to use Templates page, in Elementor Pro.

I didn't have been selected it.

Thanks to Hakkı Uçar for this
and for installing and for helping.